# Custom Core Image Filter site?

Tags: cocoa, image-processing, filter, core-image

Does any one know of any free custom Core Image filter on the net?

I was playing with Core Image today and really impressed with the vast possibility with Core Image.

Only one I did find was from [trueworders](http://www.truerwords.net/6064)